# Viewing JSON data sent from a Node backend to a public JS script

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, post, fetch

I have a simple backend that I'd like to return a string of data whenever a `POST` request is made. The string is converted to JSON, but when I see that the response was successfully received by the client (the browser), the string is missing from the response data in the browser's console.

server.js (the request handler itself is simple, there's just a few dependencies listed)

```
const path = require('path');
const express = require('express');
const bp = require("body-parser");
const request = require("request");
const {createCanvas, loadImage} = require("canvas");
const cors = require('cors');
const requestIp = require('request-ip');
const { json } = require('body-parser');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const wgServer = express();
const port = 3000;
const fs = require("fs");
const { createContext } = require("vm");

wgServer.use(cors())
wgServer.use(bp.json())
wgServer.use(bp.urlencoded({ extended: true }))
wgServer.use("/public", express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
wgServer.use(bodyParser.json({limit: '50mb'}))

wgServer.listen(port, function() {
  console.log(`Weatherglyph server succesfully listening on port ${port}.`)
});

wgServer.post('/', async function (req, res) {
  res.set('Content-Type', 'application/json');

... Lots of functions etc irrelevant to the question

let picpath = __dirname + "\\image.png";
  let picbuff = fs.readFileSync(picpath);
  let picbase64 = picbuff.toString('base64');
  console.log(picbase64);
  res.status(201).json({picbase64});
  res.send();
})})
```

script.js

```
async function submitCity(){
    let x = document.getElementById("wg_input").value;
    console.log("Successfully captured city name:", x);
    let toWeather = JSON.stringify({city: x});
    console.log("Input data successfully converted to JSON string:", toWeather);
    
    const options = {
        method: 'POST',
        mode: 'cors',
        headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
        body: toWeather
    }

    fetch('http://localhost:3000', options)
    .then(res => console.log(res))
    .catch(error => console.log(error))
}
```

Is the data (a .png converted to base64 and sent to the frontend) actually reaching the client and I just can't see it in Chrome's console, or am I sending it incorrectly?

Comment: Are you receiving an error in console? Since you are using both `res.send` and `res.status.json`. I would be very surprised if you didn't

Comment: @ShivamSood No, not at all, actually. Just a confirmation that a response was received. Is only `res.json({picbase64});` necessary?

Comment: Couple of things, I want you to try. Remove `res.set()` - not needed here. Remove `res.send()` - not needed here. Do `res.status(201).json({ pic : picbase64});`. I don't expect it to work but atleast your code would be cleaner. Also check the response on Network tab in your browser.

Comment: Thank you for the cleaner code recommendations. Unfortunately, still nothing is received. The Network tab shows, with every request, the preflight (0 bytes, status 204) and the fetch (5.5kb, status 201), but there's still nothing pertaining to the string in the console response tree dropdowns.

Comment: @ShivamSood Using `.then(res => console.log(res.json()))` works, but it's returning with `Promise: {<pending>}`. I can't figure out why, since there is a `.catch`, and nothing seems to be "unreturned" that would keep the Promise waiting for a response.

Comment: is there any specific need of async function here in the route? wgServer.post('/', async function (req, res) {

Comment: No, there isn't. That must've been a mistake. I've removed it, and the issue persists.

Comment: Furthermore, the `[[PromiseState]]:` is `fulfilled`, so why it is still pending is unresolved.